# Calculate age of record today minus table record date

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports with no training just fiddling and learning by example and by doing. I am trying to add a field to a report that will specify how old each record is in days based on the record date compared to today's date.

A fair bit of google and trying various example formulas.

For example a formula named Age with the following in it: DateDiff ("d",{Asgnmnt.DateAssign}, CurrentDate)

Actual results is that the formula is invalid.

So my database table name is Asgnmnt.DateAssign 
Which for an example record returns a date like 2019-09-06
Print Date (Date) in Crystal returns 9/12/2019
I want a field that will return the value 6
To tell me that the given example record is 6 days old
And will do that for every other record returned on the report.

Please explain any help like I am below novice thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier to do in SQL.  In your SELECT statement you can put as you had:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, Asgnmnt.DateAssign, GETDATE()) as [DaysOld]
```

Update this query in Crystal Reports and you will see the new field available to use.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I found how to add the SQL command and pasted your example. However it results in an error "the multi part identifier could not be bound". I am presently doing some google searches to try to determine how to remedy this. The source field comes from (Database Name)>(Database Name)>dbo>tables>Asgnmnt the field is DateAssign: String [##]

Comment: That error sounds like you have Asgnmnt.DateAssign twice in your SELECT or JOIN query.  I don't know what your full query looks like so I could not tell you exactly where. Just search for all locations where you have Asgnmnt.DateAssign and you should see it.